# Neo4j set default database failed

Tags: neo4j

With the Neo4j 4.0.1 Enterprise edition. I have a cluster with three Core servers. I want to set default database for them, so I edited `neo4j.conf` files and wrote `dbms.default_database=test` in each of them. After restarting the server ,the default database didn't change , it still is `neo4j`. how can I fix it?